# selecting multiple columns from a single table on Oracle with wildcards

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table TABLE_A on Oracle and it has multiple columns beginning with X. For ex. Xxaa, xxyyy, aax etc. Now I want to select fields, which begin with X. Is there any way using wildcards?

Answer (score 3):

You can build the query via dynamic SQL and then run it as you see fit:

```
declare
  SQL_QUERY   varchar2(4000);
begin
  select    'select '
         || LISTAGG(CNAME, ',') within group (order by CNAME)
         || ' from table_a'
    into SQL_QUERY
    from COL
   where TNAME = 'TABLE_A' and CNAME like 'X%';

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE(SQL_QUERY);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. John. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. You need to list each column "manually".

(Btw: this sounds like a very strange requirement and it *might* indicate a poor design - but this is hard to tell with the information you have given).

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, but you'd have to use them in the meta tables (syscolumns thingies), and then build a query and then execute it.
Be easier to do a better design, than something as fragile as that.